# Отправка команд на компьютер из Android приложения

Tags: android, c++, windows

у меня такой вопрос.
Возможно ли из своего Android приложения отправлять команды на компьютер (через Wi-Fi или Bluetooth), на котором так же будет установлена программа принимающая данные команды (на C++ к примеру) ?

Если имеет значение ОС на компе, то интересует Windows.

Что бы вы могли представить себе более понятно что имеется в виду, представьте себе что Android приложение это как пульт для телевизора, то есть пользователь выполняет действия, на комп отправляется команда, а там уже другая программа выполняет эти действия.

Я предполагаю что это возможно, но вот проблема в том что не могу найти как это реализовывается. Могли бы вы подсказать в какую сторону копать что бы понять как такое можно сделать ?
В какую сторону искать что бы понять как с android приложения отправлять команды, и в какую сторону искать что бы понять как их принимать на  С++ ?

Спасибо.

Comment: Компьютер и телефон находятся в одной сети?

Comment: Да имеется в виду для домашнего использования. Поэтому и уточнил что как вариант если есть возможность использовать Bluetooth, так как комп и телефон находятся в паре метров друг от друга.

Answer (score 3):

В случае если компьютер и девайс находятся в одной сети все предельно просто.

На компьютере запускается приложение которое прослушивает определенный заранее выбранный порт, например по протоколу UDP. Порт можно выбрать любой от 1 до 65'535, обычно рекомендуют для домашнего использования больше 60'000, т.к. они обычно не заняты.

Далее на девайсе посылаем бродкаст на выбранный порт с командой. В самом простом случае это может быть строка с кодовым словом или вообще JSON.

Преимущество UDP в том что не обязательно указывать ip адрес получателя, сообщение разошлется по всей сети, но поймет его только тот кто слушает выбранный порт и знает формат команды.

Answer (score 1):

На C пишется Web-серверер (или используется готовый), на андроиде приложение отправляет ему GET/POST-запросами команды. Я, правда, сразу вижу проблему определения адреса сервера... Можно обойтись и без специального приложения на Android, если все действия будут в браузере выполняться.

Comment: Хммм интересное предложение, не подумал о таком варианте.

Comment: Думаю, с использованием CGI можно избежать написания сервера и клиента, ограничившись только сайтом и внешними программами, которые тот будет дергать.

Answer (score 1):

1. Такое можно написать на сокетах (использовать TCP/IP протокол). Android будет выступать сокет-клиентом, а сервер - сокет-сервером. В таком случае не только Andorid может посылать команды, но и сервер!
2. Реализовать на Web-сервере (протокол HTTP). Кстати, например, вот бесплатный многопоточный веб-сервер: https://github.com/sitev/cjNetwork (сам писал ))) ). Можно взять другой бесплатный, более надёжный, например, мангуста: https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose
3. CGI/FastCGI/SCGI

Answer (score 0):

Можно через Jabber ботов организовать, можно даже через [email](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128431/)