# Передача данных с телефона на компьютер

Tags: java, android

Имеется 3 Android-устройства и компьютер. Нужно сделать так, чтобы вводились данные на телефоне (к примеру на телефоне имеется 2 кнопки, True и False. При нажатии на True, на компьютере отображается True. При нажатии на False, будет отображаться False).

Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: "Хорошая" постановка задачи. Нужно выбрать метод передачи, изначально, один из которых доступен телефону, а уже потом копать библиотеки реализующие этот метод.

Comment: Собственно, в этом и вопрос. Как организовать метод передачи, какой лучше выбрать. Код для программы будет написан на Java.

Comment: А разве большой выбор? Методов порядка 10: Проводной(USB,I2C,...) безпроводные ( IrDA, WiFi, Blue-туз, GPS, GPRS, 3G), логические (если связь уже установлена, остаётся только воспользоваться) - через интернет (HTTP, HTTPS, Socket). А тот или иной - это очень важно. Изучайте каждый из них тогда.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отправка команд на компьютер из Android приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438971/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d1%8c%d1%8e%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b8%d0%b7-android-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: Проводной вариант не рассматриваю. Только беспроводной